# Is it possible to get Durandal loading progress on app start?

Tags: javascript, jquery, durandal

We start an app built with durandal by calling `app.start()` and then setting the sell on the function that we give to the promise's `then`. Now, usually, I've seem people adding one splash screen inside the `applicationHost` div that will receive the app content during the loading of the app, however I was wondering if it was possible to get the loading progress so that we can display one progress bar being filled while the app loads.

The problem is that I couldn't think on how to get this measure of progress, nor where to put it. This because, the function inside the promise's `then` runs after the load completes, so I don't know how to intercept the process to get this measure and then fill the bar.

Is there any way to do this, or it is really not possible?

Comment: Maybe pub sub could help here. Create those progress notifications as triggered app wide events

Comment: app.start() runs a very minimal set of operations.  The real meat and bones of your application should be done after that point (loading lookup data, etc...) and you could tie into the promise of each of those operations using callbacks to increment a progress bar.  The other alternative is to show a generic progress element (HTML5) that forever loads, but that doesn't achieve much over the current implementation.

Comment: How large is your app once its compressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with events using subscriber/publisher

Create a simple loader that is design to load the viewmodel/view displaying a progress bar binded to an observable.
Next load the viewmodels and call events to indicate it's progress. Subscribe to the event on the main (loader) viewmodel and increment the progress observable.

This will allow the progress bar to increment as the modules are loading. This is really handy when using complex Root/Child route with multiple viewmodels being loaded.

The only issue is the progress increments needs to be adjusted as the code evolves.